# Rails / Ruby - map id:value pair output without interior braces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A very simple question - I currently have the following code:

```
render :json => @items.map { |item| {item.id => item.value} }
```

This outputs the in the following format:

```
[{"12":"1.6 5d"},{"13":"1.7 16V 5d"},{"14":"1.6 L 5d"}]
```

How can I reformat the code to get it to output without the interior braces? (like so):

```
{"12":"1.6 5d","13":"1.7 16V 5d","14":"1.6 L 5d"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you probably mean a hash {...} not [...]

Comment: An array of hashes is an array of hashes

Comment: Apologies, I removed the wrong type of bracket in my example - edited to correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another common trick I see, If I can get it right:

```
Hash[*@items.map { |item| [item.id,item.value] }.flatten]
```

*edit* According to others, that is ruby 1.8.6 or lower, but newer rubies can simply:

```
Hash[@items.map { |item| [item.id,item.value] }]
```

Comment: Was that an artifact from ruby 1.8 then?

Comment: yes, that was Ruby <= 1.8.6, it's a been a long time Hash[...] accepts an array of pairs (which is the sound way to define a mapping).

Comment: Awesome, I must have started this project on 1.8.6 and upgraded... Now I don't need to remember that horrific syntax :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the reduce method

```
@items.reduce({}) do |hash, kv| 
  hash[kv.first] = kv.last
  hash
end
```

Comment: Assuming that they want `{"12":...}` but that's sensible. `Hash[@items.map { |i| [i.id, i.value] }]` is another option.

Comment: <code>Hash[@items.map { |i| [i.id, i.value] }]</code> works very nicely, and is nice and simple - convert this into an answer and i'll mark it.

Comment: True, this is a much nicer answer